# Create recursive Directory structure

Tags: powershell

I would like a powershell script to create a directory structure like the following, but through the alpha numeric range.  I would like to be able to specify how many directories deep it should be.

```
0
-00
--000
--001
--002
-01
--010
--011
```

Here is what I have so far.  I am open to any suggestions for a better way of accomplishing the task.

```
## Create File structure
param([string]$RootPath = "",[int]$DirsDeep = "")

$RootPath = "C:\Temp\Catalog\"
$DirsDeep = 2


##Initializes Alpha Array
$AlphaNumericArray = @("0\","1\","2\","3\","4\","5\","6\","7\","8\","9\","A\","B\","C\","D\","E\","F\","G\","H\","I\","J\","K\","L\","M\","N\","O\","P\","Q\","R\","S\","T\","U\","V\","W\","X\","Y\","Z\")

##Function creates dirs in $CreationPath
function CreateDirs ($CreationPath) {
    foreach($Dir in $AlphaNumericArray){
        New-Item -Path $CreationPath -Name $Dir -ItemType "directory"

        }
}   
#Function to get Dir Children
function GetDirChildren ($ChildPath) {
    $DirChildren = Get-ChildItem -Path $ChildPath -Directory -Recurse
}


CreateDirs $RootPath
Write-Host $RootPath


for ($Count=0; $Count -lt $DirsDeep; $Count++){
    foreach($ChildDir in (Get-ChildItem -Path $RootPath -Directory -Recurse)){
        Write-Host $ChildDir
        Pause
        CreateDirs $ChildDir
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Does the current code work as expected?

Comment: @JosefZ in the future, please don't use Code Review as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *too broad*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Please see the section **What you should not do** in [this answer to A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: I will admit that I am new to CR, but what should go there if not a question about how to make operating code better?

Comment: I read the chat transcript that is linked on the help page and I came away with CR is for people that want to improve their functioning code. Not trying to flame a religious war, just trying to understand.

Comment: @EBGreen There's always the [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topi). Whether this question belongs on CR isn't the problem. Whether it's a valid reason to close a question is. On-topicness on other sites is irrelevant to a site's scope. Vote to close as 'too broad' instead.

Comment: Aaah...so the issue isn't whether or not it is right for CR. It is simply whether or not it is right for SO?

Comment: The code almost works as expected.  It only creates the next level directory with 1 char instead of the full path.  It also doesn't go through the directories to create the deeper levels.